# How to work with JSX in React using react-slick-slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-slick

I have a method for rendering icons:

```
public foo = (baz: any) => {
        const activeBox = this.props.activeBox;
        const disabled = this.props.disabled;

        switch (baz) {
            caseArrowsTool.name:
                return <HyatToolComponent key={baz} color={color}/>;
            case ZoomTool.name:
                return <Aloip key={baz} color={color}/>;
            case GridTool.name:
                return <Utiro key={baz} color={color}/>;
            case CropTool.name:
                return <Hello key={baz} color={color}/>;
            default:
                return null;
        }
};
```

I want these icons to render in react slick slider. How I can wrap this function in the slider like that?

```
        return (
            <Slider>
                { switch (name) {
                caseArrowsTool.name:
                    return <ArrowsToolComponent key={name} color={color}/>;
                case ZoomTool.name:
                    return <ZoomTool key={name} color={color}/>;
                case GridTool.name:
                    return <GridToolComponent key={name} color={color}/>;
                case CropTool.name:
                    return <CropToolComponent disabled={disabled} key={name} color={color}/>;
                default:
                    return null;
            } }</Slider>)
```

Comment: Typo here: `caseArrowsTool.name:` Missing space. Also to answer your question: `<Slider>{ foo(this.<props|state>.name) }</Slider>`

Comment: <Slider> {foo(name)}</Slider> is not working?

Comment: @sourav satyam No